# How to set keyboard to upper case while typing the first character? (WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to set keyboard to upper case when user is going to enter his first character in TextBox. Then I need to set keybord to lower case when user is going to enter his second character and others. Earlier I've wrote the code that just replaces the text from textbox with the text with first character in upper case. But it is wrong, I have to manipulate with screen keyboard. How to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you got that "doesn't work" or "is wrong"? What exactly have you tried? Show some code so that people can help you.

Comment: @slugster, I mean that was wrong way. I don't need to change the text I need to manipulate with keyboard. Anyway, Vyas_27 already gave what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `InputScope` Property of your TextBox Control to `"PersonalFullName"` in your XAML i.e.

```
InputScope="PersonalFullName"
```

This will help you set the first character to be upper case & the remaining lower case. Here is a [LIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) of Inputscope you can set. Hope this helps.